# Typescript module not found but webpack still builds bundle

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've reduced a problem I'm seeing down to two simple libraries:

I'm trying to create two different libraries - one is a lower level library, the other is higher level, in terms of concepts exposed to the developer.

Both are written using Typescript and build using webpack. Both are designed to be able to be used in both Node and web apps.

The problem I'm encountering is that I essentially have the Node build to be the "default" build, with the web build being the special case, so to speak. In the higher level library I'm setting the lower level library as a dependency in package.json and then importing the bundled web build. This seems to work but outputs an error.

This is the "lower level" library: https://github.com/hamchapman/typescript-lib-webpack-test

This is the "higher level" library: https://github.com/hamchapman/typescript-lib-webpack-sdk-test

The module that needs to change between the two platforms is the websocket library: faye-websocket in the Node setting and the browser `Websocket` in the web setting. I've made this work using webpack, with this config setup (in the lower level library):

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client',
  output: {
    library: 'MultiPlatformClient',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: "target/web.js"
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'transports'],
    alias: {
      'ws': 'ws.web'
    }
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ],
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  }
}
```

which is then required as follows, in `client.ts`:

```
import WebSocket from "ws";

export default class Client {
  public token: string
  public ws: WebSocket

  constructor(token: string) {
    this.token = token
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://test.com', [], {})
  }
}
```

This is all fine in the lower level library and it builds successfully with no errors.

However, this is in the package.json for the higher level library:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "multi-platform-client": "git+ssh://git@github.com:hamchapman/typescript-lib-webpack-test.git"
  }
```

with this in the `sdk-client.ts` file:

```
import Client from "multi-platform-client/web";

export default class SDKClient {
  public client: Client

  constructor(token: string) {
    this.client = new Client(token)
  }
}
```

When I run webpack I then get this output:

```
 webpack
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and /Users/Hami/Pusher/typescript-higher-test/tsconfig.json
Hash: 8fef5a551de36ef9403c
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 1633ms
               Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    ./dist/bundle.js  4.67 kB       0  [emitted]  main
./dist/bundle.js.map  5.61 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 4 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/sdk-client.ts
(1,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'multi-platform-client/web'.
```

This error is shown but the build is still successful.

Is this a problem with the typings not being specified properly? Or is it something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

@hamchapman Look at this https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/108 and this is a solution https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/pull/172/files

Comment: While that's good to know, I'm more after a solution to why the error is appearing as opposed to how I can make webpack error and not build the bundle